# TemplateSyntaxError in django when passing variable to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I receive template error "Could not parse the remainder: '{{movie_id}}' from '{{movie_id}}'" when passing the varriable to ajax. This variable works in template, but ajax cannot get it thru. Variable contains id which is required to pass to my views function.

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'make-order' {{movie_id}} %}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: new_array,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {"X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function (result) {
          console.log(result.d)
          window.location.href = "{% url 'confirmation' %}"
        },
        error: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
      });
```

urls:

```
path("make-order/<int:pk>", views.make_order, name="make-order"),
```

views:

```
def make_order(request, movie_id):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(movie_id)
        return HttpResponse(200)
    else:
        return redirect(request, 'home')
```

Comment: have you tried to remove curly braces like this {% url 'make-order' movie_id %} ?

Comment: Already resolved :) Totally changed the way of passing data and worked. I started using sessions.